# Tengo un JSP simple y quiero implementarle un determinado código AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, login

Hice una aplicación web que está dividida en 3 sub-aplicaciones, y tengo un logueo vertical a través de la librería interna de mi empresa. El problema es que cada vez que accedo a la aplicación, aparentemente hay más de una solicitud (posiblemente porque se cargan las 3 aplicaciones), y debo loguearme 3 veces, lo cual ya no lo necesito porque automáticamente las librerías utilizan unas credenciales predefinidas en mi equipo como logueo. Lo que requiero es que ya no aparezca la ventana de usuario y contraseña. Me explicaron que con el código anterior, y según yo, se debería aplicar al *JSP*.

El siguiente *JPS* me redirige a la página principal de mi aplicación web:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String url = "/sisalbmReporte/grafico?action=graficoGeneral";
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que necesito es implementar lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields:{
        withCredentials:true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar hacerlo de esta forma:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>JSP Page</title>  
 </head>
 <body>   
    <%
      String url = "/sisalbmReporte/grafico?action=graficoGeneral";
      response.sendRedirect(url);
    %>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(e) {
         $.ajax({
              xhrFields:{
              withCredentials:true                  
              }                 
           });
   });
  </scritp>
```

En lo que llames a la pagina .jsp se ejecutra el ajax. Espero te sirva Saludos!